# What's the meaning of "take forever"?

Tags: phrases

From NPR: [Wheels On The Bike Go Round And Round (To Make Music)](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=269457757)

The story tells that Baber--a music writer, create music out of bikes.

> BABER: For instance, when you pluck a spoke on a wheel, you're not just hearing one, you're hearing all of them. They all ring out from sympathetic vibration. So the way to solve that was to tune every single spoke to the exact same pitch, which ***takes forever***.

What's the meaning of "take forever" here? Forever to the same pitch after tuning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two idioms here:

> *It takes time* means "time is required". *It takes a long time* means "a long time is required".
>
> *Forever* is a colloquial exaggeration, understood as "a very long time".

So *which takes forever* means "which requires a very long time".

Answer (score 3):

To say something "takes forever" is simply hyperbole to mean it takes a very long time.